# How to Delete Excel Worksheet after selecting it's name from Table using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table containing all worksheet names in my Excel file.
I'm trying to delete the worksheet after selecting the cell containing its name.

```
Sub Delete_Active_Rows()
    Dim deletedcell As String
    deletedcell = Rows(ActiveCell.Row)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets(deletedcell).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Delete
End Sub
```

I get:

> Run-time error '13':
> Type mismatch

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Sub SheetKiller()
    Dim s As String, r As Range
    
    s = ActiveCell.Value
    Set r = ActiveCell.EntireRow
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Sheets(s).Delete
    Application.displayalrers = True
    r.Delete
End Sub
```

Try to avoid deleting the sheet containing the button!

Comment: After executing the code, the sheet was deleted without deleting the active cell, and i got this error :    `Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error you're getting is due to a typo in the answer provided by Gary, this should do the trick:

```
Sub SheetKiller()
    Dim s As String, r As Range
    
    s = ActiveCell.Value
    Set r = ActiveCell.EntireRow
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Sheets(s).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    r.Delete
End Sub
```

The issue was caused by the second "Application.DisplayAlerts" being misspelled.

If you wanted to safeguard against accidentally deleting the sheet that contains the table with all of the worksheet names, you could wrap the last bit of the procedure in a conditional statement like so:

```
Sub SheetKiller()
    Dim s As String, r As Range
    
    s = ActiveCell.Value
    Set r = ActiveCell.EntireRow
    
    If s <> ActiveSheet.Name Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Sheets(s).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        r.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```